# how to add words to a text after expanding it in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I expanded a text box in Illustrator and then edited it, however I can not add any words/letters to this text now.

How can I add words to this text, or even how can I know the size of that text to write another identical one?

Comment: If you’re asking how to un-outline text or how to find attributes such as point size and font for outlined text then you can’t. It’s impossible.

Answer (score 5):

Expanded (outlined) type can not be edited like live type.

When you "Create Outlines" or "expand" a text object you convert it to standard vector objects, making it no different than a series of rectangles and circles. It no longer retains *any* text information such as font, face, kerning, type size, etc.

You'll have to retype anything if you need to edit it.